# opengl texture from pixmap

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm looking to avoid loading textures from files and want to include the textures in header files. I can store images in a header with pixmaps, but do not know how to then load them as a texture in OpenGL. Does anyone know how to do this?

I am using a framework (FLTK) already so cannot use Qt/GTK etc.

**EDIT: update:**

I've manually gone through the pixmap and made an array of floats of the rgb values stored in an array `float *img`. I then bind the texture manually.

So explicitly whereas I once had only

```
texture = SOIL_load_OGL_texture("filename", SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS);
```

I now have

```
texture = pixmaptotexture(somepixmap);
```

where pixamaptotexture is my own function which does this

```
GLuint pixmaptotexture(const char **p){

    //convert pixmap to array of floats in array called img assigned dynamically.

   //ie:

   //some code here to find width (w) height (h), number of colours and what they are etc. from pixmap

   float* img = new [w*h*3];

   for (int i=0;i<w;i++){
       for (int j=0;j<h;j++){

          //some code goes here to determine rgb value from pixmap
           img[i*w+j*h+0]=r;
           img[i*w+j*h+1]=g;
           img[i*w+j*h+2]=b;
       }
   }

   GLuint TexID;
   glGenTextures(1, &TexID);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TexID);
   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, w, h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, img);
   delete []img;

   return TexID;
}
```

But now the texture is not working. What am I doing wrong? Everything else in my code is identical. I literally just swap out the soil loader line with my function.

**SECOND EDIT:**

So I have now stored the raw pixels in a header file, but I cannot get the texture to work

This works:

```
texture = SOIL_load_OGL_texture("filename", SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS);
```

Now I replace it with

```
   glGenTextures(1, &texture);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TexID);
   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, w, h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, img);
```

where img is a pointer to the array of pixels. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: so you've embedded the image, and you can read the raw data, but now you want to put it in a format GL can read? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Pretty much. Up til now I have been using SOIL so have let it do all the leg work. By read the raw data I presume you mean I can access the pixmap, yes, but I guess I'm asking is how to convert that into an array of pixels I can load as a texture. Is there some library or is it all going to be legwork? Clarification on the format conversion would be ideal if that is the case (what does opengl expect, what format are the colours in pixmaps stored as etc.)

Comment: @user3353819: If you already have the raw data embedded, then you have to just pass *that* to OpenGL's glTexImage2D function (first allocating a texture name with glGenTextures).

Comment: I understand, I think. However, I think there is an intermediate step of converting the pixmap into an array of pixels each with an rgb component before you can just 'pass' is to OpenGL? I was wondering if there was an existing way to do this. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Please see edits for update

Comment: get your pixels back from the texture and write raw bitmap array initializer yourself

Comment: @j-p Sorry, I don't understand. Everything I've seen requires you to put it in a raw pixel array format and pass it to OpenGL, which I'm doing. I literally don't know what you mean get my pixels back from the texture or why I would possibly want to do that.

Comment: Load your normal image file, create a texture with it, get back your raw pixels array from opengl(formating is alright for reloading), and create your header yourself. No need of extra transformations after that...but maybe it's not your problem. I see in your code you are iterating thrue all your pixels, try to avoid that in runtime part of you prog

Comment: Ok, I understand, but that's just an efficiency question right? My question now is why is my approach not working?

Comment: Also, I have no idea how to implement what you are suggesting. How do I get opengl to spit out pixels?

Comment: Getting back your pixels from gl (`glGetTextImage`) will give you an array that you may provide 'unchanged' to your `glTexture` function. So you just need to store your array in a convenient form: one single byte array for example

Comment: I've managed to get my textures in a single array format through `glGetTexImage` (although the headers end up being rather large, I guess that's the downside of this approach), but I am still in the same situation of the above code not working. Yes I can pass the pixels into `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, w, h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, img);` but this wasn't working for me. I don't know what you mean by `glTexture` function